# raspberry pi audio drivers not working with python

Tags: audio, driver, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a problem where I have been trying to get a raspberry pi to run this program* but it keeps giving me this error I have tried reinstalling the drivers, changing over the input and output to different things, and making sure the raspberry pi is picking up the audio chip but no luck does anyone have a solution?

error :

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:823:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib conf.c:5200:(snd_config_expand) Unknown parameters {AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2  CARD 0}
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958:{AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2  CARD 0}
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:823:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib conf.c:5200:(snd_config_expand) Unknown parameters {AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2  CARD 0}
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958:{AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2  CARD 0}
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1514
Expression 'ValidateParameters( inputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_In )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2818
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/main.py", line 42, in <module>
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 383, in adjust_for_ambient_noise
    assert source.stream is not None, "Audio source must be entered before adjusting, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?"
AssertionError: Audio source must be entered before adjusting, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/main.py", line 55, in <module>
    print("Error:", e)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 189, in __exit__
    self.stream.close()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import openai
import pyttsx3
import time

# set up OpenAI API credentials
openai.api_key = "your-openai-key-here"

# set up text-to-speech engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

# define function to send text to ChatGPT and print response
def send_to_chat(text):
    try:
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="text-davinci-002",
            prompt=text,
            max_tokens=1024,
            n=1,
            stop=None,
            temperature=0.7
        )
        response_text = response.choices[0].text.strip()
        print(response_text)
        engine.say(response_text)
        engine.runAndWait()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending text to ChatGPT:", e)

# define keyword to start speech recognition
keyword = "command"

# set up speech recognition with microphone input device index 1
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)

# continuously listen for audio input from the microphone
while True:
    with mic as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        print("Listening for keyword...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            if text.lower() == keyword:
                print("Keyword detected!")
                engine.say("Keyword detected")
                engine.runAndWait()
                break
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            pass
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Error:", e)

# start listening for commands
while True:
    with mic as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        print("Listening for commands...")
        engine.say("Listening for commands")
        engine.runAndWait()
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print("You said:", text)
            send_to_chat(text)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            pass
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Error:", e)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Unexpected error:", e)

        # reset back to listening for the keyword after each request is completed
        print("Listening for keyword...")
        engine.say("Listening for keyword")
        engine.runAndWait()
        while True:
            audio = r.listen(source)
            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                if text.lower() == keyword:
                    print("Keyword detected!")
                    engine.say("Keyword detected")
                    engine.runAndWait()
                    break
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                pass
            except sr.RequestError as e:
                print("Error:", e)
```

Comment: Hello, please always provide minimal reproducible examples for code questions like that. Here it looks like the question concerns  `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise`.

Comment: Are you sure there's a microphone with device index 1? You don't verify that in your code.

Comment: This is an issue with either `ALSA` or `jack`, rather than with your Python code. What is the output of `arecord - l`? Have you tried `alsamixer` to select a different card or device? Is the `jack` server log showing any errors?